# Why cannot find Webligic the JNDI name for an EJB?

Tags: maven, ejb, weblogic, javabeans, jndi

I have an **EAR** file, the structure shows the **EJB** s inside:

```
project-ear
        |-----project-business.jar
                        |-----SupervisorProcesserBean(class) (@Stateless)
                        |-----SupervisorProcesserBeanLocal(interface) (@Local)
        |-----project-dao.jar
                        |-----SupervisorDAOImpl(class) (@Stateless)
                        |-----SupervisorDAOLocal(interface) (@Local)
```

Here is my **SupervisorDAOImpl** bean:

```java
@Stateless
public class SupervisorDAOImpl implements SupervisorDAOLocal {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() {
        //do something
    }
}
```

with it's **SupervisorDAOLocal** interface:

```java
@Local
public interface SupervisorDAOLocal {
    public void doSomething();
}
```

And my **SupervisorProcesserBean** bean:

```java
@Stateless
public class SupervisorProcesserBean implements SupervisorProcesserBeanLocal {
    @EJB
    private SupervisorDAOLocal supervisorDao;
    ....
}
```

with it's **SupervisorProcesserBeanLocal** interface:

```java
@Local
public interface SupervisorProcesserBeanLocal {
    ....
}
```

You can see, I want to inject **SupervisorDAOLocal** to **SupervisorProcesserBean**.
When I want to deploy it to **weblogic**, I get this error:

```
Error resolving ejb-ref "com.viktor.business.SupervisorProcesserBean/supervisorDAO" 
from module "project-war-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war" of application "project-ear-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT". 
The ejb-ref does not have an ejb-link and the JNDI name of the target Bean has not been specified.
```

How could it be? Both bean has a Local interface.

Comment: What does your web.xml (under WEB-INF) in your war look like? Sounds like it's missing ejb info. Reference: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/webapp/configureresources.html

Answer (score 0):

The JNDI name is built using the remote interface's name which you don't seem to have one. Change the @Local annotation to @Remote and try again.